# How to make use of the ActionBar Support Libary on Android 2.1

Tags: android, import, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am stuck at Support Android 2.1 and above section of the Android Developer Guide.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

I tried to extend my MainActivity class with ActionBarActivity just like the guide said. However, it does not exist.

It looks like it is just called ActionBar now. I used the ActionBar import but this caused all my MainActivity methods to go red. I tried removing the @Overrides and fixed some of the error. I still have a number of errors though and I feel like I'm drifting further away.

I pulled back my code to before working on supporting 2.1. I would appreciate it any help trekking this.

Comment: You are probably missing the support lib. Did you add it?

Comment: I added the library as instructed in the guide. I have android-support-v7-appcompat in my Package Explorer. Added the jar files in the libs folder to my build path. After all that, I configured the support lib in my application's build path. I'm wondering if I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android 2.1, **download the ActionBarSherlock Library** by Jake Wharton, and **add it to your project:**

Simply follow the steps here:

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/

Also take a look here for great **examples** on how to use the ActionBarSherlock:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples

You can also look here of you want to use the **official support Library** and how to set it up:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: I noticed that the guide skips the Action Bar section. I am focusing on the Action Bar guide for now before going into Sherlock. On that note, is it still worth learning Action Bar if there is Sherlock?

Comment: If you want to support Android versions below 4.0, I would definitely look into ActionBarSherlock, as it is a very good library and also recommended by Google. Furthermore, it can of course be used in higher Android versions as well

Comment: I already downloaded the support library and set it up just like the guide instructed. However following the guide further produces numerous exceptions. I am still new but would it be wise to give up on the guide and use Sherlock instead?

Comment: Thats up to you. I have never worked with the support Library so I dont really know if its hard to use or worth looking into. But I have worked with ActionBarSherlock and use it in almost all my projects that involve lower Android verstions. In my opinion it is pretty easy to setup and use, and I did not have any problems so far.

Comment: Thanks! I would appreciate if you could provide me other great resources for learning beginning Android.

Comment: I would recommend that you learn the Java basics before you get to Android. If you already know all that, you could get started here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: Sadly, the Action Bar section of that training link is where it caused my problems. I might skip that section but I am afraid it could affect the following sections.